# Ubuntu: Postgresql not using ram

Tags: ubuntu, memory, postgresql

I have a 4GB 2 core Ubuntu droplet that doesn't seem to properly make use of the RAM and CPU.

I have tried to optimize the settings in `postgresql.conf` to match the instance with (based on pgtune):

```
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 3GB
work_mem = 26214kB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
```

... After inserting this I reloaded the configs and restarted the server.

However, when opening `htop` the process (which is owned by the `postgres` user) only uses 1 core and approx. 5% of the available RAM.

[image: htop screenshot]

Here is `top`

```
Tasks: 124 total,   2 running, 120 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 50,0 us,  0,2 sy,  0,0 ni, 49,8 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   4048268 total,  3890804 used,   157464 free,    24012 buffers
```

Here is `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3953       3800        153       1065         23       3367
-/+ buffers/cache:        409       3544
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Any suggestions what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know anything about Postgresql configuration, but haven't you allocated 4.5GB on a machine with 4GB of RAM? What about the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql does not split a task onto different cores by default (and I am not aware you can easily add this functionality), it might however execute different queries on different cores.

Anyway there does not seem to be anything wrong so don't bother.